# How to replace if else dict python odoo-14

Tags: python, odoo-14

I have a set of records. How do I replace all 'if' with 'dict'?

```
department_dict = {} #I'm stuck at this point.

for department in reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_line_ids.mapped("department_id.name"):
    if department == 'CPA':
       ....

    if department == 'New MB':
            new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(1, reconciliation_act.partner_id.commercial_company_name)
            new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(2, reconciliation_act.currency_id.display_name)
            new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(7, sales_new_mb)
            new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(8, 'New MB')

            if reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_date == reconciliation_act.period_to:
                new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(11, empty_string)
                new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(12, 'начисление выручки')
            else:
                sheet.write(row, 11, reconciliation_act.period_to, date_period)
                new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(13, 'корректировка выручки прошлых периодов')

            for col_num, data in enumerate(new_mb_department_no_discount):
                sheet.write(row, col_num, data, col_format)
            sheet.write(row, 0, reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_date, date)
            sheet.write(row, 4, total_new_mb, col_format_number)
            sheet.write(row, 5, date_with_customer_ref, date)
            row += 1

    if department == 'Alfasearch':
       ....
    if department == 'inApp':
       ....
```

I do a report for each department line by line. Here's an example of what I do

Comment: What do the elipsis' do?

Comment: @Sayse Inside the 'if' there is a lot of logic for creating reports.I want to speed up the program so that it is less cumbersome and remove the 'if'.

Comment: Making a dictionary won't speed it up all that much more than if you'd changed it to use `if/elif`

Comment: If your goal is to speed up the program replacing the `if`s with a `dict` is not the solution, any improvement it might give is negligible. You probably should focus on the reports logic.

Comment: Seriously this is a wrong tack.  We can argue about dict lookup vs if/elif from a style pov but it won't help speed, certainly not in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and did it this way

```
sales_cpa = 'Sales CPA'
sales_inapp = 'Sales Inapp'
sales_alfasearch = 'Sales Alfasearch'
sales_new_mb = 'Sales New MB'
departments_dict = {
    'CPA': sales_cpa,
    'New MB': sales_new_mb,
    'Alfasearch': sales_alfasearch,
    'inApp': sales_inapp,
}

for reconciliation_act in account_reconciliation_act_ids:
    row += 1
    date_from = reconciliation_act.period_from.strftime("%d.%m") if reconciliation_act.period_from else "?"
    date_to = reconciliation_act.period_to.strftime("%d.%m") if reconciliation_act.period_to else "?"
    customer_ref = reconciliation_act.customer_ref or ''
    date_with_customer_ref = f"{date_from}-{date_to} {customer_ref}"
    for department in reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_line_ids.mapped("department_id"):
        total_by_departments = sum(reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_line_ids.filtered(
            lambda rec: rec.department_id.id == department.id).mapped("price_subtotal"))
        total_by_departments_with_discount = sum(reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_discount_ids.filtered(
            lambda rec: rec.department_id.id == department.id).mapped("discount_amount"))

        departments = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
        departments.insert(1, reconciliation_act.partner_id.commercial_company_name)
        departments.insert(2, reconciliation_act.currency_id.display_name)
        departments.insert(7, departments_dict.get(department.name))
        departments.insert(8, department.name)

        if reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_date == reconciliation_act.period_to:
            departments.insert(11, empty_string)
            departments.insert(12, revenue_accrual)
        else:
            sheet.write(row, 11, reconciliation_act.period_to, date_period)
            departments.insert(13, revenue_adjustment_from_previous_periods)

        for col_num, data in enumerate(departments):
            sheet.write(row, col_num, data, col_format)

        sheet.write(row, 0, reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_date, date)

        if reconciliation_act.apply_discount:
            total_by_departments = \
                total_by_departments - total_by_departments_with_discount or total_by_departments
        sheet.write(row, 4, total_by_departments, col_format_number)
        sheet.write(row, 5, date_with_customer_ref, date)
        buyer = reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_discount_ids.filtered(
            lambda rec: rec.department_id.id == department.id).buyer_id.name or ''
        sheet.write(row, 9, buyer, col_format)
        row += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def handle_NEWMB_department(new_mb_department_no_discount,
                          reconciliation_act,
                          sales_new_mb,
                          empty_string,
                          date_period,
                          sheet,
                          row,
                          col_format,
                          date,
                          total_new_mb,
                          col_format_number,
                          date_with_customer_ref):
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(1, reconciliation_act.partner_id.commercial_company_name)
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(2, reconciliation_act.currency_id.display_name)
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(7, sales_new_mb)
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(8, 'New MB')

    if reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_date == reconciliation_act.period_to:
        new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(11, empty_string)
        new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(12, 'начисление выручки')
    else:
        sheet.write(row, 11, reconciliation_act.period_to, date_period)
        new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(13, 'корректировка выручки прошлых периодов')

    for col_num, data in enumerate(new_mb_department_no_discount):
        sheet.write(row, col_num, data, col_format)
    sheet.write(row, 0, reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_date, date)
    sheet.write(row, 4, total_new_mb, col_format_number)
    sheet.write(row, 5, date_with_customer_ref, date)
    print("New MB")


def handle_CPA_department(**kwargs):
    print("CPA")


department_dict = {"CPA": handle_CPA_department, "New MB": handle_NEWMB_department}

for department in reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_line_ids.mapped("department_id.name"):
    department_dict.get(department)(new_mb_department_no_discount,
                          reconciliation_act,
                          sales_new_mb,
                          empty_string,
                          date_period,
                          sheet,
                          row,
                          col_format,
                          date,
                          total_new_mb,
                          col_format_number,
                          date_with_customer_ref)
```

can this solve the problem?

Comment: Why do we need to create functions?

Comment: I am not sure what your actual codes are under each department, so I assume that there are some logic, but it is up to you

Comment: and the logic will be written in functions? For example in def handle_NEWMB_department(**kwargs) ?

Comment: function is one way, or you can use staticmethod or instances of classes and call one function of the instance

Comment: it is a better practice change if else if else to a map

Comment: I will change the question and show what the logic is in one of the departments

Comment: yeah you can move the code under one department to a standalone function for better understanding and you know follow the open-close principle

Comment: Friend, how do you make one method per department?

Comment: What if I didn't have 4 departments and everything was in one function?

Comment: still you can directly move all the code to a standalone function, and feed the function with params that it need from previous content

Comment: could you give an example to understand? I haven't quite figured it out.

Comment: I changed the post, so it just ugly as hell, cuz there are a lot of params, perhaps we can put all the params in one object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246365/discussion-between-maks-and-wu-hoyt).

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you aren't going to make it run faster by removing the if statements. But for the sake of discussion I'll show you how to do what you asked, literally using a dict to select the action:

```
def handle_CPA_department():
    # do whatever you do with CPA ....

def handle_new_MB_department():
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(1, reconciliation_act.partner_id.commercial_company_name)
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(2, reconciliation_act.currency_id.display_name)
    # etc...

# Write other functions to handle other departments

# This is where you map department names to functions
department_dict = {'CPA': handle_CPA_department,
                   'New MB': handle_new_MB_department,
                   # Plus other entries for other departments
                  }

for department in reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_line_ids.mapped("department_id.name"):
    # Call the function associated with the department
    handler = department_dict[department]
    handler()
    # Or do it on one line: department_dict[department]()
```

There are a couple of drawbacks to this approach. First, it's not the most readable code - you have to pay attention to notice that `department_dict` maps department names to functions. Second, every handle_* function has to take the same arguments (as I have it written, no arguments).

A related alternative is to get rid of the dict and just use `if/elif`:

```
def handle_CPA_department():
    # do whatever you do with CPA ....

def handle_new_MB_department():
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(1, reconciliation_act.partner_id.commercial_company_name)
    new_mb_department_no_discount.insert(2, reconciliation_act.currency_id.display_name)
    # etc...

# Write other functions to handle other departments

for department in reconciliation_act.reconciliation_act_line_ids.mapped("department_id.name"):
    if department == 'CPA':
        handle_CPA_department()

    elif department == 'New MB':
        handle_new_MB_department()

    # More elif's for additional departments

    else:
        print("Unrecognized department")
```

This approach is more readable since it uses the obvious and familiar `if`/`elif`. This approach also lets you pass data as arguments to each function, and unlike the previous example, the data you pass doesn't have to be the same for every department.

Comment: Let's say I have 4 if department = '...'
a lot of fields are repeated.
Can I make one function for all four departments?

Comment: @Maks You can write a function that handles the common pieces, then have the department-specific functions call the common function. Or you can put that common code above the if statements in your existing code. Lots of options here.

Answer (score -1):

What is the elements you want in your dict ?

You can make a list of dict if you have need like this

```
list_dict = [
{"name": "name1", "id": 1, "length": 100, "right": True},
{"name": "name2", "id": 2, "length": 200, "right": False},
...
]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The question was easy to misinterpret, so don't feel bad. But yeah, this isn't what the OP was asking.